# React.js array .push() is taking multiple values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, react-hooks

I am working on a simple blog website as my first Web Dev project. In the page where I write a blog, I am using a simple svg icon with an onClick listener to add a paragraph to the blog. This works like Medium where when you click on the "+" icon, it adds a new paragraph for you to write. Here is the code of my onClick event listener function:

```
function addNewPara() {
        // let newContent = {
        //     date: blogContent.date,
        //     author: blogContent.author,
        //     title: blogContent.author,
        //     contentArray: blogContent.contentArray.push("")
        // };
        // setBlogContent(newContent);

        setBlogContent(prevValue => {
            prevValue.contentArray.push("")
            return {
                ...prevValue,
            }
        });
    }
```

This has two ways where I update the state value. The issue here is that when I click the plus icon and this method is triggered, it pushes two empty strings into the `contentArray` key.

If I uncomment and switch to the other method, I get the following error:
`TypeError: blogContent.contentArray.map is not a function`

The `TypeError` occurs where I am using the array to render the relevant HTML elements. What could be the issues behind this?

Comment: You have not provided enough code to analyse, I can only assume that setBlogContent is some sort of state update, but then why would you modify previous state (prevValue)?

Comment: Did you try to `console.log(Array.isArray(blogContent.contentArray))` and `console.log(blogContent.contentArray)`? I think the problem might be that what you expect to be an array actually is not an array

Comment: @Lukasz'Severiaan'Grela the Udemy course suggested that way wherein we can use the prevValue. Also, reading your comment makes me realize the stupid mistake I was making. I was modifying the previous value and then adding more to that array. Hence it added two new values instead of one. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should be your setable method

```
setBlogContent({...blogContent, contentArray: [...blogContent.contentArray, "your new item"]})
```